# Capitalizing 5th word in Python string?

Tags: python

I understand how to capitalize first word using `!CITY_NAME!.capitalize()`.  However, if I have a string in a record and I want to capitalize the fifth word, what is the code for that?

Ex: `3 Boundary in fifth column` How do I capitalize `column`?

I can use: `'column'.replace('c','C')` but is there a way to call the capitalize function and not replace to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general function to capitalize any number of words that works for any length:

```
#s: string
#x list of words to capitalzie
def cap1(s, x):
    split = s.split(" ") #Split by spaces
    output = []

    #Use enumerate as a counter to check index
    for i,sub in enumerate(split, 1):
        #Capitalize only if it's the xth word
        if i in x:
            output.append(sub.capitalize())
        #Otherwise, leave it alone    
        else:
            output.append(sub)

    return " ".join(output) #Rejoin with spaces

#As a one-liner user generators...much simpler
def cap2(s, x): 
    return " ".join((sub.capitalize() if i in x else sub for i,sub in enumerate(s.split(" "), 1)))

print(cap2("this capitalizes the fifth word in this test", [5]))
print(cap2("what if we want multiple words?", [1,3,6]))

s = "how about the last word only?"
print(cap2(s, [len(s.split(" "))]))
```

Output:

```
this capitalizes the fifth Word in this test
What if We want multiple Words?
how about the last word Only?
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
text = "3 Boundary in fifth column"

split_text = text.split(" ")

if len(split_text) >= 5:
    fifth_word = str(split_text[4]).capitalize()
    split_text[4] = fifth_word

print " ".join(split_text)
```

Comment: I was curious how Python handled splitting a string with numbers. Everything stays a string, e.g. `type("this 1 test".split(" ")[1])`